# Why has this navigation bar appeared like this?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I wanted to have a navigation bar that has white text links without it underlined but instead it has appeared with basic links in a div so hasn't worked but I don't know what is missing.

Any suggestions would be apricated.

```html
<html>
<style>
.box3{
  padding:7px;
  background: black;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size:15px;
 }
 </style>
 
 <div class="box3">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
 </div>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you think that code *should* make the links white and not underlined: It doesn't address the links, and mentions nothing about text colour, nor white, nor underlining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add style to your links, for example you can add

```
.box3 a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

This will change the color to white and remove the underline.

`.box a { css }`  will only target the a tags inside of the box3 div

```css
.box3 {
  padding: 7px;
  background: black;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.box3 a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box3">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```